# Two Simultaneous Splash Screens in Cordova

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I'm building an app in Cordova for iOS and Android - just wondering if there's a straightforward way to have 2 simultaneous splash screens (one for the app name and one for the organisation that has contributed to the app). I know people don't like splash screens but the client has requested them in the design specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiples splash screens in the same app.

But a workaround can be :

1. Show Splash Screen
2. Hide Splash Screen ( [doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#splashscreen.show) )
3. Show a full screen SVG image to make your second splash

Comment: Cheers for that :)